# Cannot read property <propety Name> of undefined although it is initialized in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I created template-driven form as part of learning Angular2.
When trying to display the form, I'm getting an error claiming: **"Cannot read property 'FirstName' of undefined"**, although I initialized the business object (worker) in the declaration of the class. It consist even if I initialize it in the constructor.
See My code ("lean" version):
Html(EditWorker.component.html):

```
<input id="firstNameId" type="text" [(ngModel)]= worker.FirstName ... />
```

EditWorker.component.ts:

```
export class EditWorker 
{
    constructor(){}
    worker : Worker = new Worker();
```

Worker.model.ts:

```
export class Worker implements IWorker{
...
FirstName:string;
...
constructor(){}
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate inside the constructor

```
 worker : Worker 
 constructor(){
  this.worker  = new Worker();
}
```

Comment: Nop, tried it before, trying it now - doesn't help.

Comment: OK - thanks.I'm aware that it should work. There was probably a problem with the way the application bootstraped - I've changed the way it is bootstarped (directly to the component I was interested in) and it worked. Thanks @Sajeetharan

Comment: upvote if the answer help,also add your solution to the question itself

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that the initialize solution should work. There was probably a problem with the way the application bootstraped - I've changed the way it is bootstarped (directly to the component I was interested in) and it worked. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

did you try to change **worker.FirstName** to **worker?.FirstName**

```
<input id="firstNameId" type="text" [(ngModel)]= worker?.FirstName ... />
```

?

Comment: Yes, I did - you are right - this should be an early check, but the problem was binding between wrong component and HTML file

Comment: Nice to know you found the solution